# Unknown column in 'on clause' - Error SQL (1054)

Tags: mysql, sql

Antes de nada indicar que he intentado buscar mi respuesta aquí pero no encuentro ningún ejemplo que se asemeje al mío.

Quiero obtener los datos de una tabla de actividades con sus correspondientes documentos, pero la tabla `ACT` no es visible al parecer desde dentro de la `Select` que utilizo en el `IFNULL`.

La tabla `TLACTIVIDADES` recoge las actividades. `X_ACTIVIDAD` es el `PK` y `X_DOCUMENTO` es UN `FK` con los documentos recogidos en `TLDOCPDF` y `TLDOCURL`
La tabla `TLDOCACT` relaciona las actividades con los documentos, teniendo 2 `FK`: `X_ACTIVIDAD` y `X_DOCUMENTO`, que relaciona las tablas `TLACTIVIDADES` Y (`TLDOCPDF` o `TLDOCURL`). Además tiene otra columna TIPO que indica si el tipo de documento es PDF o URL.

El error que me devuelve es

> Error SQL (1054). Unknown column ACT.X_ACTIVIDAD in 'on clause'.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que `ACT` sea visible desde el `IFNULL`? Cuando trabajo en Oracle esto sí que se puede hacer, pero en MySQL no me lo permite. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
    SELECT ACT.*, 
IFNULL((SELECT X_PDF FROM TLDOCPDF PDF
    JOIN TLDOCACT DOC ON DOC.X_DOCUMENTO = PDF.X_PDF
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT1 ON ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD = DOC.X_ACTIVIDAD AND ACT.X_ACTIVIDAD = ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD), 0) AS 'X_PDF',
IFNULL((SELECT X_URL FROM TLDOCURL URL
    JOIN TLDOCACT DOC ON DOC.X_DOCUMENTO = URL.X_URL
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT1 ON ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD = DOC.X_ACTIVIDAD AND ACT.X_ACTIVIDAD = ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD), 0) AS 'X_URL'    
FROM TLACTIVIDADES ACT    
WHERE ACT.X_EVENTO = 10 ORDER BY ACT.F_ACTIVIDAD ASC
```

Comment: Tampoco estoy muy puesto en el tema, pero he hecho alguna cosa parecida y creo que esto podría ayudarte. [Joins en MySQL](https://www.vichaunter.org/desarrollo-web/joins-mysql-bien-explicado-lo-necesitas-saber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de dar con el problema que tenía.
Estaba intentando relacionar las tablas cuando realmente tenía que añadir una condición. Así me devuelve los resultados correctamente. 
Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

```
SELECT ACT.*, 
IFNULL((SELECT X_PDF FROM TLDOCPDF PDF
    JOIN TLDOCACT DOC ON DOC.X_DOCUMENTO = PDF.X_PDF
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT1 ON ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD = DOC.X_ACTIVIDAD
    WHERE ACT.X_ACTIVIDAD = ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD), 0) AS 'X_PDF',
IFNULL((SELECT X_LOCATION FROM TLDOCLOC LOC
    JOIN TLDOCACT DOC ON DOC.X_DOCUMENTO = LOC.X_LOCATION
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT1 ON ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD = DOC.X_ACTIVIDAD
    WHERE ACT.X_ACTIVIDAD = ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD), 0) AS 'X_LOCATION',
IFNULL((SELECT X_URL FROM TLDOCURL URL
    JOIN TLDOCACT DOC ON DOC.X_DOCUMENTO = URL.X_URL
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT1 ON ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD = DOC.X_ACTIVIDAD
    WHERE ACT.X_ACTIVIDAD = ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD), 0) AS 'X_URL'    
FROM TLACTIVIDADES ACT  
WHERE ACT.X_EVENTO = 10 ORDER BY ACT.F_ACTIVIDAD ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Debería funcionar haciendo el JOIN a ACT en la condición si no es nulo, ya que necesita que la consulta del select interno pueda ejecutarse de modo independiente:

```
SELECT ACTF.*, 
IFNULL((SELECT X_PDF FROM TLDOCPDF PDF
    JOIN TLDOCACT DOC ON DOC.X_DOCUMENTO = PDF.X_PDF
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT1 ON ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD = DOC.X_ACTIVIDAD
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT ON ACT.X_ACTIVIDAD = ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD), 0) AS 'X_PDF',
IFNULL((SELECT X_URL FROM TLDOCURL URL
    JOIN TLDOCACT DOC ON DOC.X_DOCUMENTO = URL.X_URL
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT1 ON ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD = DOC.X_ACTIVIDAD 
    JOIN TLACTIVIDADES ACT ON ACT.X_ACTIVIDAD = ACT1.X_ACTIVIDAD), 0) AS 'X_URL'    
FROM TLACTIVIDADES ACTF    
WHERE ACTF.X_EVENTO = 10 ORDER BY ACTF.F_ACTIVIDAD ASC
```

Comment: He probado esta query y me sigue devolviendo los resultados incorrectos, pues al final me muestra para todas las actividades los documentos de la primera actividad...

Comment: Entendí mal lo que querías, ya veo que lo has resuelto, sería más bien un inner join en lugar de join

Comment: Es probable sí... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Carmen.